# Examples of iOS Protection Classes

Tags: ios, security

What are some examples of the types of files that would utilize each of the iOS's four protection classes, on iPhones with the A7 chip? For example, which class for an app vs. user login data for the app. The iOS Security documentation only gives one example. I'm developing training for digital forensics students, and examples help them get it. https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Comment: what's you need specify??

Comment: http://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/iphone/why-apples-a7-chip-is-so-much-better-than-other-smartphones-3512169/ - its help you

Comment: I need examples of the types of files in the different iOS protection classes.

Comment: This page shows how to extract the protection class: http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/10/18/extracting-data-protection-class-from-files-on-ios/
The author shows that Facebook.plist has the protection class NSFileProtectionNone. If others have extracted classes from files on iOS, I would like to know some of these classes so I can include them in examples for students.